# Audiotrack doesn't stop with audioTrack.stop() since last Android version

Tags: android, audiotrack

I'm using an Audiotrack for looping some music.

I was using the method audioTrack.stop() to stop, but since the last update it doesn't work.
From the last version only this way works:

```
audioTrack.pause();
audioTrack.flush();
```

But this method doesn't stop the audio in the previous Android versions. Anyone knows what method works in all the Android versions ?

Comment: What version was this in reference to?  I'm having trouble stopping audio tracks on Android 5.0.1.  I cannot seem to stop them with any of the methods.

Comment: See my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28713301/1953590